# Undefined method when setting up mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get mailers set up in my application (for the first time) so that when a users question is answered they are notified via email.

My problem is I am unable to get the controller working without errors.

My routes look like this:

```
 resources :questions do
   resources :answers
 end
```

In my answers_controller I have this:

```
def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])

if @answer.save
  UserMailer.question_answer(@user).deliver
 end 
end
```

In the user_mailer.rb file I have this:

```
 def question_answer(user) 
   @answer = Answer.new
   @question = @answer.question
   mail(:to => @question.user.email, :subject => "Your question was answered!")  
 end
```

However, when posting an answer I get this error:

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: `@user` must be nil when it's being passed from the create action. Make sure `@user` is in scope there.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused. The error underlines the third line in user_mailer.rb but should i still add something like '@user = @question.user' in the create action?

Comment: yeah, It won't error until it tries to use nil. It won't have any problem being passed nil. So it means you need to go back and figure out why it's nil. Try that exact line right after `if @answer.save`

Comment: No, no luck with adding that line.

Comment: Seems like mail(:to => @question.user.email) is the problem. @question might be nil.

Comment: What is Answer.new in mailer? why you creating new answer in mailer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass @answer in parameter like,

```
UserMailer.question_answer(@answer, @user).deliver
```

and you will get question from @answer. in mailer.rb

```
def question_answer(answer, user) 
  @answer = answer
  @question = @answer.question
  @user = user
  mail(:to => @question.user.email, :subject => "Your question was answered!")  
end
```

Now you will get each parameter to pass with email. in your question i figure out that you are passing only user and getting that user with question, but you will have a blank @question so user of that question will be blank. that's why you were getting nil class error.

Hope this help.